# Swift UIButton titleLabel not showing correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I am developing an iOS application with Swift / UIKit. I have a UIButton that updates its titleLabel property after a request to an API is successful when the main view appears. The problem I'm having is that it **sometimes!!** only displays half of the string in the UIButton. To be more specific, the request to the API returns the value of the current UVI and the title of the button is updated to `"6 UVI"` (for instance) and only the `6` is shown.

Here is what I do:

```
//Main View
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        makeAPIRequest()
    }

    func makeAPIRequest() {
        //Making the request ....
        button.setTitle("\(requestResultUV) UVI", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The thing is that it only happens sometimes, so running this very same code a few times it can show the full string in the button or not, it is really weird...
I would appreciate if anyone knows what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: check your constraints and set style of button to default

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd wager the API call is being made on something other than main queue. Try wrapping button.setTitle(:normal:) in `DispatchQueue.main.async { // do stuff }`.

Comment: Show us your actual code. If you are using async code like an URLSession request, its completion handler is likely called on a background thread. You can't do UIKit calls from a background thread, so as Adrian says, you probably need to wrap your UI updates in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`.

Comment: Your are right. I update the button text inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` in the completion handler of the API call. But the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have found the issue, thanks to Abdur Rehman for pointing this out. I just needed to change the **style** of the button to **default** and this makes the problem disappear. Thanks all!